# How to find consecutive rows based on the value of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have some data. I want to group them based on the value of `data` column. If there are 3 or more consecutive rows that have data bigger than 10, then those rows are what I want.

So for this data:

```
use tempdb;
go
set nocount on;

if object_id('t', 'U') is not null
drop table t;
go

create table t
(
    id int primary key identity,
    [when] datetime,
    data int
)
go

insert into t([when], data) values ('20130801', 1);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130802', 121);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130803', 132);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130804', 15);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130805', 9);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130806', 1435);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130807', 143);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130808', 18);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130809', 19);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130810', 1);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130811', 1234);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130812', 124);
insert into t([when], data) values ('20130813', 6);

select * from t;
```

What I want is:

```
id          when                    data       
----------- ----------------------- -----------
2           2013-08-02 00:00:00.000 121        
3           2013-08-03 00:00:00.000 132        
4           2013-08-04 00:00:00.000 15         
6           2013-08-06 00:00:00.000 1435       
7           2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 143        
8           2013-08-08 00:00:00.000 18         
9           2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 19
```

How to do that?

Comment: I think you have your output wrong. How are 15, 9, 1435, all above 10.

Comment: "consecutive" requires the rows been ordered. So what I mean "consecutive" is first order all the rows by id, then use the ordered result as the base of "consecutive".

Comment: For "15, 9, 1435", 9 is less then 10.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT *,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY cnt) pt  FROM
    (
        SELECT tt.*
           ,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t WHERE data <= 10 AND ID < tt.ID) AS cnt
        FROM  t tt
        WHERE data > 10
    ) t1
)

SELECT id, [when], data FROM cte WHERE pt >= 3
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e5f4/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
id  when                    data
2   2013-08-02 00:00:00.000 121
3   2013-08-03 00:00:00.000 132
4   2013-08-04 00:00:00.000 15
6   2013-08-06 00:00:00.000 1435
7   2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 143
8   2013-08-08 00:00:00.000 18
9   2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 19
```

**EDIT**

First the inner query counts the no of records where data <= 10

```
SELECT tt.*
     ,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t WHERE data <= 10 AND ID < tt.ID) AS cnt
FROM  t tt
```

output

```
id  when                    data   cnt
1   2013-08-01 00:00:00.000 1       1
2   2013-08-02 00:00:00.000 121     1
3   2013-08-03 00:00:00.000 132     1
4   2013-08-04 00:00:00.000 15      1
5   2013-08-05 00:00:00.000 9       2
6   2013-08-06 00:00:00.000 1435    2
7   2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 143     2
8   2013-08-08 00:00:00.000 18      2
9   2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 19      2
10  2013-08-10 00:00:00.000 1       3
11  2013-08-11 00:00:00.000 1234    3
12  2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 124     3
13  2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 6       4
```

Then we filter the records with data > 10

```
WHERE data > 10
```

Now we count the records by partitoning cnt column

```
SELECT *,COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY cnt) pt  FROM
(
    SELECT tt.*
        ,(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM t WHERE data <= 10 AND ID < tt.ID) AS cnt
    FROM  t tt
    WHERE data > 10
) t1
```

Output

```
id  when    data                   cnt  pt
2   2013-08-02 00:00:00.000 121     1   3
3   2013-08-03 00:00:00.000 132     1   3
4   2013-08-04 00:00:00.000 15      1   3
6   2013-08-06 00:00:00.000 1435    2   4
7   2013-08-07 00:00:00.000 143     2   4
8   2013-08-08 00:00:00.000 18      2   4
9   2013-08-09 00:00:00.000 19      2   4
11  2013-08-11 00:00:00.000 1234    3   2
12  2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 124     3   2
```

The above query is put in cte just like temp table

Now select the records that are having the consecutive count >= 3

```
SELECT id, [when], data FROM cte WHERE pt >= 3
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

```
;WITH partitioned AS (
  SELECT *, id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS grp
  FROM t
  WHERE data > 10
),
counted AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) AS cnt
  FROM partitioned
)

SELECT id, [when], data
FROM counted
WHERE cnt >= 3
```

[**Reference URL**](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/find-n-consecutive-free-numbers-from-table)

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e5f4/8)

Answer (score 4):

First, we discount any row that has a value of 10 or less:

```
WITH t10 AS (SELECT * FROM t WHERE data > 10),
```

Next, get the rows whose immediate predecessor is also more than 10:

```
okleft AS (SELECT t10.*, pred.id AS predid FROM
   t10
   INNER JOIN t pred ON 
        pred.[when] < t10.[when]
        AND pred.[when] >= ALL (SELECT [when] FROM t t2 WHERE t2.[when] < t10.[when])
   WHERE pred.data > 10
),
```

Also get the rows whose immediate successor is also more than 10:

```
okright as (SELECT t10.*, succ.id AS succid FROM
   t10
   INNER JOIN t succ ON
        succ.[when] > t10.[when] 
        AND succ.[when] <= ALL (SELECT [when] FROM t t2 WHERE t2.[when] > t10.[when])
   WHERE succ.data > 10
),
```

Finally, select any row where it either starts a sequence of 3, is in the middle of one, or ends one:

A row whose valid right side also has a valid right side starts a sequence of at least 3:

```
starts3 AS (SELECT id, [when], data FROM okright r1 WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT NULL FROM okright r2 WHERE r2.id = r1.succid)),
```

A row whose predecessor and successor are both valid is in the middle of at least 3:

```
mid3 AS (SELECT id, [when], data FROM okleft l WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT NULL FROM okright r WHERE r.id = l.id)),
```

A row whose valid left side also has a valid left side ends a sequence of at least 3:

```
ends3 AS (SELECT id, [when], data FROM okleft l1 WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT NULL FROM okleft l2 WHERE l2.id = l1.predid))
```

Join them all up, with UNION to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT * FROM starts3
UNION SELECT * FROM mid3
UNION SELECT * FROM ends3
```

SQL Fiddler: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12f3a/9

Edit: I like BVR's answer, much more elegant than mine.