# SQL: detecting consecutive blocks of sequential rows with same key

Tags: sql, sequence, window-functions

My problem boils down to the following. I have a table with some natural sequencing, and in it I have a key value which may repeat over time. I want to find the blocks where the key is the same, then changes, and then comes back to being the same. Example:

1. A
2. A
3. B
4. B
5. B
6. C
7. C
8. A
9. A
10. C
11. C

Here I want the result to be

1. A, 1-2
2. B, 3-5
3. C, 6-7
4. A, 8-9
5. C, 10-11

so I can't use that key value A, B, C to group by, because the same key can appear multiple times, I just want to squeeze out repetitive occurrences that are uninterrupted.

Needless to say, I want the simplest SQL one can come up with. It would use OLAP window functions.

I am usually pretty good with complicated SQL, but with sequences I am not so good. I will work on this a little bit myself, of course, and annex some ideas below this question in a subsequent edit.

Let's begin by defining the table for our discussion:

```
CREATE TABLE Seq (
  num integer,
  key char
);
```

---

UPDATE 1: doing some research I find a similar question here: [How to find consecutive rows based on the value of a column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436749/how-to-find-consecutive-rows-based-on-the-value-of-a-column) but both the question and the answers are wrapped up into a lot of extra stuff and confusing.

UPDATE 2: I already got one answer, thanks. Inspecting it now. Here is my test I am typing into PostgreSQL even as we speak:

```
CREATE TABLE Seq ( num int, key char );
INSERT INTO Seq VALUES 
   (1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), 
   (2, 'B'), (3, 'B'), (5, 'B'), 
   (6, 'C'), (7, 'C'), 
   (8, 'A'), (9, 'A'), 
   (10, 'C'), (11, 'C');
```

UPDATE 3: First contender of a solution is this

```
SELECT key, min(num), max(num)
  FROM (
    SELECT seq.*,
           row_number() over (partition by key order by num) as seqnum
      FROM Seq 
  ) s
  GROUP BY key, (num - seqnum) 
  ORDER BY min;
```

yields:

```
 key | min | max
-----+-----+-----
 A   |   1 |   2
 B   |   2 |   3
 B   |   5 |   5
 C   |   6 |   7
 A   |   8 |   9
 C   |  10 |  11
(6 rows)
```

for some reason B repeats twice, I see why, I made a "mistake" in my test data, skipping sequence num 4 and going straight from 3 to 5.

This mistake is fortunate, because it allows me to point out that while in this example the sequence number is discrete, I am intending the sequence to arise from some continuous domain (e.g., time).

There is another "mistake" I made, in that I have num 2 repeated. Is that allowable? Probably not. So cleaning up the example, removing duplicate but leaving the gap:

```
DROP TABLE Seq;
CREATE TABLE Seq ( num int, key char );
INSERT INTO Seq VALUES 
   (1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), 
   (3, 'B'), (4, 'B'), (6, 'B'), 
   (7, 'C'), (8, 'C'), 
   (9, 'A'), (10, 'A'), 
   (11, 'C'), (12, 'C');
```

this still leaves us with the duplicate B block:

```
 key | min | max
-----+-----+-----
 A   |   1 |   2
 B   |   3 |   4
 B   |   6 |   6
 C   |   7 |   8
 A   |   9 |  10
 C   |  11 |  12
(6 rows)
```

Now going with that first intuition by Gordon Linoff and trying to understand it and add to it:

```
SELECT s.*, num - seqnum AS diff 
  FROM (
    SELECT seq.*,
           row_number() over (partition by key order by num) as seqnum
      FROM Seq
    ) s
  ORDER BY num;
```

here is the num - seqnum trick before grouping:

```
 num | key | seqnum | diff
-----+-----+--------+------
   1 | A   |      1 |    0
   2 | A   |      2 |    0
   3 | B   |      1 |    2
   4 | B   |      2 |    2
   6 | B   |      3 |    3
   7 | C   |      1 |    6
   8 | C   |      2 |    6
   9 | A   |      3 |    6
  10 | A   |      4 |    6
  11 | C   |      3 |    8
  12 | C   |      4 |    8
(11 rows)
```

I doubt that this is the answer quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

This answers the original problem.

You can enumerate the rows for each key and subtract that from `num`.  Voila!  This is number is constant when the `key` is constant on adjacent rows:

```
select key, min(num), max(num)
from (select seq.*,
             row_number() over (partition by key order by num) as seqnum
      from seq
     ) s
group by key, (num - seqnum);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d36ef6169a228bdf494bb295032daaa) is a db<>fiddle showing that it works.

Comment: not quite, I am showing the results of your query above.

Comment: @GuntherSchadow . . . You changed the data -- and the definition of the problem.  The original problem implied (very strongly) that the nums had to differ by 1 to be in the same group and were gapless and sequential.  You entirely changed the problem; asking a *new* question is better than invalidating answers.

Answer (score 1):

Because of gaps you can't use `num` directly as Gordon's solution suggested. `Row_number` it too.

```
select key, min(num), max(num)
from (select seq.*,
             row_number() over (order by  num) as rn, 
             row_number() over (partition by key order by num) as seqnum
      from seq
     ) s
group by key, (rn - seqnum)
order by min(num);
```